# min value on the diagonal of matrix exponential

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, matrix-exponential

I'm trying to compute the minimum value along the diagonal of $\exp(-A)$ efficiently:
$$\min \mathrm{diag}(\exp(-A))$$
Where $A$ is positive semidefinite.
Is there a way of relating this quantity to some norm of $A$, or to a function of its eigenvalues? If not, can I bound it?

Comment: What do you mean by $\min\mathrm{diag}$? As far as I get it, $\mathrm{diag}(\exp(-A))$ is a matrix, not a scalar

Comment: is $A$ diagonalizable?

Comment: I meant the lowest value along the diagonal of $\exp(-A)$. Yes, A is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m=min(diagonal(e^{-A}))$ and $spectrum(A)=\lambda_1\geq\cdots\geq \lambda_n\geq 0$. There is $i$ s.t. $m=e_i^Te^{-A}e_i$. Thus $e^{-\lambda_1}\leq m\leq e^{-\lambda_n}$.

Also, one has $m\leq \dfrac{1}{n}tr(e^{-A})=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_ie^{-\lambda_i}$.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Isn't this valid for all the elements along the diagonal of $\exp(-A)$?

Comment: The inequalities in line 2 are valid for any diagonal element but not the inequality in line 3.